# Load in batch a list

Tags: r

I have a list

```
str(my_list)
 chr [1:121] "http://www.myexamplesite.com"  ...
```

And I use it as input in the following loop

```
for (i in 1:length(my_list)) {
  url <- my_list[i]
  #more code
}
```

The problem I have is if something goes wrong for a value of the list i.e. for number 90 the list stops from the error and I can't have the next values.
Is there any possible way to load the values one by one so I will not have a problem?

Comment: Function `try` might help.

Comment: There are several functions in `R` to catch errors. See `?try` and `?tryCatch`.

Comment: @Pascal  thank I show the syntax but because I don't know in depth how to use it is there any place in my code I should put it exactly?

Comment: Please follow @nicola advice: read `?try` and `?tryCatch`. Also, you certainly can find example of use in Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment, but just to show an example on the use of `try`. Let's suppose that you have a line that may produce the error. You enclose it in `try` and test what happens. For instance, say you have a loop like this:

```
for (something in set) {
  ...
  #this is the line
  x<-dangerousFunction(args)
  ...
}
```

You can:

```
for (something in set) {
  ...
  #this is the line
  x<-try(dangerousFunction(args))
  if (class(x)=="try-error" ) {
     cat("something happened at ",something,"\n")
     next
  }
  #do normal stuff
  ...
}
```